# jQuery on click main menu items won't show child sub menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I'm building a custom mobile menu in Wordpress and I'm having trouble hiding and showing sub menu items. I'm using the class name `.menu-item-has-children` as my selector, and I'm targeting the child classes `.sub-menu` to toggle.

My issue is the sub-menus will only close if visible and won't reopen again on click of the parent element.

**View example here (use the inspector to view mobile menu < 1200px):**

http://dev-inspired-spine.pantheonsite.io/

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function() {
  var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
  if ($(submenu).is(':hidden')) {
    $(submenu).slideDown(200);
  } else {
    $(submenu).slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-24685" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-24685"><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-24731" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24731"><a href="#">Our Innovation Approach</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24732" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24732"><a href="#">BLog</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24733" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24733"><a href="#">Newsroom</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-24686" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-24686 et-touch-hover et-show-dropdown et-hover"><a href="#">Conditions</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-24734" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24734"><a href="#">Degenerative Disc Disease</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24735" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24735"><a href="#">Degenerative Scoliosis</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24736" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24736"><a href="#">Disc Herniation</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24737" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24737"><a href="#">Facet Joint Syndrome</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24738" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24738"><a href="#">Spinal Stenosis</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24739" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24739"><a href="#">Spondylolisthesis</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24740" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24740"><a href="#">Thoracic Disc Disease</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24741" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24741"><a href="#">Arthritis of Spine</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24742" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24742"><a href="#">Fractures</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24743" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24743"><a href="#">Myelopathy</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24744" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24744"><a href="#">Radiculopathy</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24745" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24745"><a href="#">Spine Deformities</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-24687" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-24687"><a href="#">Treatments</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-24746" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24746"><a href="#">Spinal Fusion Facts</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24747" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24747"><a href="#">OLLIF</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24748" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24748"><a href="#">MIS-DLIF</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24749" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24749"><a href="#">MIS-DTIF</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24750" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24750"><a href="#">SI Joint Fusion</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24751" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24751"><a href="#">Laminectomy</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24752" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24752"><a href="#">Laminoplasty</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-24688" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-24688"><a href="#">Patient Experience</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-24690" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24690"><a href="#">New Patient Forms</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24753" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24753"><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24754" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24754"><a href="#">Coverag</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-24689" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24689"><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: try this in your Javascript code: `$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing what you suggested and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed you site, for mobile `(<1200 px)` - you have links for parent menus, so after clicking on parent menu, the page gets redirects to the respective link. So try this in your Javascript code.

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
  if ($(submenu).is(':hidden')) {
    $(submenu).slideDown(200);
  } else {
    $(submenu).slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

Hope this may help you.